# List all applications - output as text file

Tags: macos, list, text, applescript

I was just wondering how someone would go about finding all the applications that are installed on Mac OS X 10.5 using preferably applescript and output all their application names to a text file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the applications installed under Mac OS X are registered in the [Launch Services](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Reference/LaunchServicesReference/Reference/reference.html) database.

The Launch Services framework contains a helper shell command `lsregister` which among other uses can dump the information stored in the Launch Services database. Under Mac OS X 10.5 and 10.6 that command is located in the following folder:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister
```

Using a few simple grep filters one can extract the full paths of all registered applications:

```
lsregister -dump | grep --after-context 1 "^bundle" | grep --only-matching "/.*\.app"
```

Putting it all together, the following AppleScript will compute the user visible names of all registered applications using the [info for](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW14) command:

```
property pLSRegisterPath : "/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister"

set theAppPaths to every paragraph of (do shell script pLSRegisterPath & " -dump | grep --after-context 1 \"^bundle\" | grep --only-matching \"/.*\\.app\"")

set theNames to {}
repeat with thePath in theAppPaths
    try
        copy displayed name of (info for (thePath as POSIX file)) to end of theNames
    end try
end repeat
choose from list theNames
```

Comment: is there anyway to do this so that it does not give me full paths it just gives me the application name?

Thank you for your answer though,

Comment: @Taylor: I have updated the script. Now it computes the user visible name of each registered application.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few methods in [this post](http://macosx.com/forums/howto-faqs/26204-howto-list-your-installed-applications.html), depending on how in-depth you want your search to be. Also not sure if that's exactly the output format you want, but you can probably tweak it for your specific needs.

Comment: Oops: the requested page could not be found.

Answer (score 1):

I use the system_profiler command to get my text.  Then you can parse as needed.

```
system_profiler SPApplicationsDataType
```

...

```
AppleScript Utility:

  Version: 1.1.1
  Last Modified: 5/18/09 10:34 PM
  Kind: Intel
  64-Bit (Intel): Yes
  Location: /System/Library/CoreServices/AppleScript Utility.app
```

maybe pipe it to a text file and then use sed ....

Bash commands can be called through applescript if you want to have an application or you can save the script with a .command extension and the user will be able to double-click on it.

Comment: This seems much cleaner than the `lsregister` approach, but it is quite a bit slower.

Answer (score 1):

For poeple like me using bash scripting to reach their goals here is a bash variant of the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

path='/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support'
$path/lsregister -dump | grep -A 1 "^bundle" | grep --only-matching "/.*\.app" | awk -F "/" '{ print $NF }' | awk -F "." '{ print $1 }'
```

This gives a list of all apps without the .app extension.

Comment: Much simpler and much faster :).

Answer (score 0):

**AsObjC solution**:

```
use AppleScript version "2.5" -- EI Capitan and later
use framework "Foundation"
use scripting additions

set plistString to do shell script "system_profiler -xml SPApplicationsDataType"
set dataString to current application's NSString's stringWithString:plistString
set plistData to dataString's dataUsingEncoding:4
set propertyList to current application's NSPropertyListSerialization's propertyListWithData:plistData options:0 format:(missing value) |error|:(missing value)
set allItems to (propertyList's objectAtIndex:0)'s objectForKey:"_items"
set theDictionary to allItems's dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:{"_name", "version", "path", "arch_kind", "obtained_from", "lastModified", "signed_by"}


-- |version| of theDictionary as list  -- versions list
-- |path| of theDictionary as list  -- Posix paths list
-- arch_kind of theDictionary as list -- architecture list
-- obtained_from of theDictionary as list -- developer name list
-- (lastModified of theDictionary) as list -- lastModified dates list 
-- signed_by of theDictionary as list -- software signings list of lists
_name of theDictionary as list -- app names list
```

**NOTE**: I get above the list of installed application Names. Uncomment corresponding code line to get Versions, Posix paths (and so on) list.

Answer (score 0):

System_profiler can output json, which powershell (pwsh in osx) can turn into objects.  Or save the json (or xml) to a file.

```
system_profiler SPApplicationsDataType -json | convertfrom-json |
  % SPApplicationsDataType | ? _name -match slack

_name          : Slack
arch_kind      : arch_arm_i64
lastModified   : 10/17/2023 6:19:47 PM
obtained_from  : mac_app_store
path           : /Applications/Slack.app
signed_by      : {Apple Mac OS Application Signing, Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority, Apple Root CA}
version        : 4.34.121
```