# how to get all installed applications with Objective C in OSX

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I need to get all installed application on the OSX using objective c

I googled and found someone suggesting to do this with terminal command:

I am running this command on terminal

> "system_profiler SPApplicationsDataType -xml"

to find all applications but I am not able to retrieve the terminal data from code behind.

please provide a way to fetch all installed applciations or at least please let me know to get terminal command result from objective c.

tons of thanks in advance

Comment: And now please type 100 times: "C is **not** Objective-C is **not** C!"

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21091532/cocoa-get-list-of-installed-applications

Comment: @Olaf, actually we are able to use C code with objective C that is why i had tagged C. thanks

Comment: Wea are also able to use Fortran code with C code, Python with C++ code, etc. Still no reason to just add all tags. That contradicts the idea of tagging.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the NSFileManager Class to list all the item from the /Applications directory.

```
NSArray *urls = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSApplicationDirectory inDomains:NSLocalDomainMask];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *properties = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: NSURLLocalizedNameKey,
                       NSURLCreationDateKey, NSURLLocalizedTypeDescriptionKey, nil];

NSArray *array = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] 
                 contentsOfDirectoryAtURL:[urls objectAtIndex:0]
               includingPropertiesForKeys:properties
                                  options:(NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsHiddenFiles)
                                    error:&error];
if (array == nil) {
    // Handle the error
}
```

Apple Doc Reference:

NSFileManager Class
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000305-SW24

File System Programming Guide
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/AccessingFilesandDirectories/AccessingFilesandDirectories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH3-SW25

Comment: Tons of thanks to yu @deniel Albertini. Could you tell me how to parse the name of Application from the paths present in Array.

Comment: 'for (NSURL *appUrl in array) { NSString *appName = [[appUrl lastPathComponent] stringByDeletingPathExtension]; }' should do the trick. Sorry for the formatting I'm writing this from my phone.

Comment: Works in sandbox!